# Functions are not working (my first C project)

Tags: c, binary, hex, decimal

**Hello, I am a college student new to C and this is my first project to work on. Here is the description:**

Write a program that takes in n arguments but requires at least 3 arguments.

The first argument should be the base in which you are providing numbers in.
The second arguments should be the base you want to convert to.
The third, fourth, and all the way up to n is a sequence of numbers that need to be converted

```
 ./Aassign1 decimal binary 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Bases to cover:
I want you to be able to be able to convert numbers back and forth from Decimal, Hex, and binary.

The structure of your code:

I would like you to write 9 side-effects free (meaning they don't change their input) functions for converting between bases. This means you will need to use `malloc` to return a 2D array of the result:

```
char ** decimalToDecimal (...)
char ** decimalToBinary (...)
char ** decimalToHex (...)

char ** binaryToDecimal (...)
char ** binaryToBinary (...)
char ** binaryToHex (...)
char ** hexToDecimal (...)
char ** hexToBinary (...)
char ** hexToHex (...)
void seekUserInput (...)
*** inputValidation (...)
int main (...)
```

Based on the first two arguments you should pass in the rest of them and then return another new array with the result, which you can then iterate through.

Remember that arrays cannot be passed around if they are allocated on the stack so make sure to allocate them onto the heap. Don't forget to free your memory too!

---

**Here is my code. The function somehow is not working. I tried to print the third argument value but it is also not working. I don't know whether the user input is being into the function or not. Please give me some advice. I compiled it to an exe and then, using cmd to run the program, for example, p1.exe decimal decimal 12, it looks like compare string such as decimal, binary, hex are ok, but the argv[2] which seems do not go into the function. When I ran p1.exe decimal decimal 12, it only turned out "system exit." which I expected it would print decimal out( because I am doing decimal to decimal)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char ** result;


char ** decimalToDecimal (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("%d", argv[2]);
}

char ** decimalToBinary (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int p = 1, r = argv[2];

    char *result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

    itoa(r, result, 2);

    return result;
}

char ** decimalToHex (int argc, char* argv[])
{

}

char ** binaryToDecimal(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int p = 1, r = argv[2];

    char *dec = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

    itoa(r, dec, 10);

    return dec;
}

char ** binaryToBinary (int argc, char* argv[]) {

}

char ** binaryToHex(int argc, char* argv[])

{
    int p = 1, r = argv[2];

    char *hex = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

    itoa(r, hex, 16);

    return hex;
}

char ** hexToDecimal (int argc, char* argv[]) {

}
char ** hexToBinary (int argc, char* argv[]) {

}
char ** hexToHex (int argc, char* argv[]) {

}

// Redirect to corresponding function
void seekUserInput(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (strcmp(argv[0], "binary") && strcmp(argv[1], "decimal")) result = binaryToDecimal(argc, argv);
  else if (strcmp(argv[0], "binary") && strcmp(argv[1], "binary")) result = binaryToBinary(argc, argv);
  else if (strcmp(argv[0], "binary") && strcmp(argv[1], "hex")) result = binaryToHex(argc, argv);
  else if (strcmp(argv[0], "decimal") && strcmp(argv[1], "decimal")) result = decimalToDecimal(argc, argv);
  else if (strcmp(argv[0], "decimal") && strcmp(argv[1], "binary")) result = decimalToBinary(argc, argv);
  else if (strcmp(argv[0], "decimal") && strcmp(argv[1], "hex")) result = decimalToHex(argc, argv);
  else if (strcmp(argv[0], "hex") && strcmp(argv[1], "decimal")) result = hexToDecimal(argc, argv);
  else if (strcmp(argv[0], "hex") && strcmp(argv[1], "binary")) result = hexToBinary(argc, argv);
  else if (strcmp(argv[0], "hex") && strcmp(argv[1], "hex")) result = hexToHex(argc, argv);

  return result;
}

// Check if user input contains letters
bool inputValidation(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if( strcmp(argv[0], "binary") || strcmp(argv[0], "decimal")) {
    for (int i=2;i<argc;i+=1)  {
      char *pos = argv[i];
      while (*pos != '\0')  {
        if ( !isdigit(*(pos++)) ) return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc <= 3) {
        printf("ERROR: You have to insert at least 3 argumetns.");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
  result = (char**) malloc(argc*4);
    if ( inputValidation(argc, argv) )
    seekUserInput(argc, argv);


  printf("%s\n", "System exit.");
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Is the code compiling? If not you can share how you try to compile it and the error.

Comment: I compiled it to a exe, and then using cmd to run the programme, for example, p1.exe decimal decimal 12, it looks like compare string such as decimal, binary, hex are ok, but the argv[2] which seems do not go into the function. When I ran  p1.exe decimal decimal 12, it only turned out "system exit." which I expected it would print decimal out( because I am doing decimal to decimal).

Answer (score 0):

You have mass error in your code almost all your code

### 1.run this and see what is argv[0]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n",argc);
    printf("%s\n",argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

### 2.type error

all your char ** change to char *

### 3.type error

int p = 1, r = argv[2];

change to

int p = 1;

char* r = argv[2];